# GUI terminal issue - empty rectangular boxes instead of normal characters

Tags: linux, gnome, fonts, gnome-terminal, desktop

I am getting boxes in place of characters in a Red Hat GUI terminal. How do I solve this?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried changing fonts?

Comment: I ran across a similar situation; we ended up resolving it by installing `ghostscript`, which I suspect had the real solution buried underneath it.

Comment: Do these characters appear right away after opening new terminal window?